# How to horizontally center <div> in container while keeping them aligned to the left if line is incomplete

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to center `innerContainer` inside `outerContainer` while keeping multiple `<div>` inside `innerContainer` aligned to the left if the line is incomplete.

I would also like the containers to be fluid and stay centered at all time

Like this

[image]

or this

[image]

I tried with and without `flexbox`. I am open to all proposals. This is an example of my code.

Even if I put a `width` to the `innerContainer`, it doesn't always stay centered

```css
.outerContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.innerContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 80%; /* Does not stay center in all cases */
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.insideDiv {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 250px;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerContainer">
  <div class="innerContainer">
    <div class="insideDiv"></div>
    <div class="insideDiv"></div>
    <div class="insideDiv"></div>
    <div class="insideDiv"></div>
    <div class="insideDiv"></div>
    <div class="insideDiv"></div>
    <div class="insideDiv"></div>
    <div class="insideDiv"></div>
    <div class="insideDiv"></div>
    <div class="insideDiv"></div>
    <div class="insideDiv"></div>
    <div class="insideDiv"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: do you need to support IE aswell?

Comment: @tacoshy No, I dont need support for IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to use `flexbox` to horizontally center a `block level element` such as a `<div> box`. This can be easily done by using `margin: 0 auto;` on the block element that you trying to center.

I changed your innerbox to `display: grid;` I used it with `repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));` I changed your 250px to 100px for demonstartaion purpose. That line will fit as many boxes as possible with that width and resize them slightly to not waste empty space. also I removed the class from those boxes and adress them with CSS directly.

```css
.outerContainer {
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.innerContainer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  border: 3px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.innerContainer > div {
  min-height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerContainer">
  <div class="innerContainer">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```